# Custom repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have in my project a few entity that have the same property (for sample 'name') so, it's possible to create a repository with a custom select to use in that's entities? so instead I extend my repository from JpaRepository  I extend MyCustomJpaRepository  and the MyCustomJpaRepository extends the JpaRepository to grant the basic functions from JpaRepository too?

tks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can define a common interface repository which extends JpaRepository by marking it with the annotation @NoRepositoryBean:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
  //common methods
}
```

However, you still must have a dedicated interface for each of your concrete entities which extend this custom interface.